# How can I search an HTML img title attributes in a table?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, .net

[image: I have a form like in the image.]

** 1st, 2nd and 3rd columns search bars are operational. My `AssignedUser` column consists of images and their titles (User Name) which appear when you move the cursor over them. How can I fix the search bar in this column?

Here are my Javascript codes that I use for my search in 1st, 2nd and 3rd columns;  **

```
var column = $(this);
$('#userList1 thead tr').clone(true).appendTo('#userList1 thead');
$('#userList1 thead tr:eq(1) th').each(function (i) {
    var title = $(this).text();
    var thID = $(this).attr('id');

  
    if (thID != "nosearch"/* && thID != "selectoption"*/) {
        $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search " id="searchbox"/>');

        $('input', this).on('keyup change', function () {
            if (table.column(i).search() !== this.value) {
                table
                    .column(i)
                    .search(this.value)
                    .draw();
            }
        });
    }
```

**My `img` tag is as follows;**

```
if (item.AssignedUserPhoto != "") {
    <img id="profilePhotoimg" name="@item.AssignedUserID" src="@item.AssignedUserPhoto" value="@item.ID" title="@item.AssignedUserNAme")" />
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `"How can I fix the search bar in this column?"` ?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius thank you for your question. You're right, I skipped a sentence :) My 1st, 2nd and 3rd columns search bars run properly, but the same code does'nt work on 'AssignedUser' column. Also there is no error, but it doesnt work. I think I need to write another code for this column, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: It appears you are duplicating IDs with your code which will cause problems with any code that relies upon an ID to identify an element in the DOM. Can you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to illustrate the issue?